# SQLiteDataReader, last Read() takes 10 seconds

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a database with approx 20 million rows and 3 columns, testing without index for the moment. My select statement is like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   database 
WHERE  column COLLATE NOCASE IN ('expr1', 'expr2' .... up to 96 expressions)
```

The `command.ExecuteReader()` returns immediately and I can read the collection right away. But the last `Read()` which returns no more rows takes 13 seconds, why is this..? How can this be improved..?

```
using (SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if(reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // READING DB DATA
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Moved HasRows out of loop

Comment: Have you tried taking that `reader.HasRows` off? And what job is it really doing there?

Comment: `reader.HasRows` in a loop is redundant. `reader.HasRows` tells whether reader has atleast one row or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite computes result records on the fly.

After the last record that actually matches, the database still has to check all the remaining records for a match.

An index would make the lookups faster.
(Use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to check if some index is used.)